# using mcrypt_create_iv in php

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error, mcrypt

Ok so i am geting this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv() in ..... on line 8
```

Now ive done some reading and found out that i need to install or update my php, problem is im not using my university server and cant update it, well at least i don't think i can.

Is there a simple way around this.

Hash.php

```
    <?php
class Hash {
    public static function make($string, $salt = '') {
        return hash('sha256', $string . $salt);
    }

    public static function salt($length) {
        return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
    }

    public static function unique() {
        return self::make(uniqid());
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires the `mcrypt` extension.  If you can't install that, then you can't use `mcrypt_create_iv`.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php

Comment: Ok, hmm il try work around this. thank you for the infomation

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mcrypt.
If using a Debian-based Linux system, you can run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: I think apt will actually restart apache for you when installing, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Im using windows, hmm is there a way around this?

Comment: @Beep: How did you install PHP?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat I have not installed php, I am using sublime text on a windows laptop then use filezila to upload on to a hosted account.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you might be able to easily install apache, php, mysql from http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper